# copying userdomain into clipboard error

Tags: c#

i have a problem with my little program.

I created a button that should copy the current userdomain into my clipboard when i press it.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Clipboard.SetText(System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.
      GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName);
    }
```

But VS always gives me an error when i Debug the program and press the button.

```
System.ArgumentNullException ist aufgetreten.
HResult=0x80004003
Nachricht = Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.
Parametername: text
Quelle = System.Windows.Forms
Stapelüberwachung:
at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(String text, TextDataFormat 
format)
at WindowsFormsApp1.Window.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 
2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:line 120
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, 
Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 
msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.#
System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNat
iveMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 
reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 
reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 
reason, ApplicationContext context)
at WindowsFormsApp1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual 
Studio 2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Program.cs:line 18
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for some reason this line of code `System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName` returns `null` or an *empty-string* in your case. According to the MSDN `Clipboard.SetText` throws an exception if the argument **null or empty**.

Have you tried `Environment.UserDomainName`?

Comment: "Have you tried Environment.UserDomainName?" thank you for that <3